# Using DataTable.Compute to evaluate Case When

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, c#-4.0, datatable

I am trying to evaluate an expression like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Compute("Case When 'Test'='Test' Then 1 Else 0 End", "")
```

But i get the following error:

```
'dt.Compute("Case When 'Test'='Test' Then 1 Else 0 End", "")' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.SyntaxErrorException' object {System.Data.SyntaxErrorException}
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx): "The *expression* parameter requires an aggregate function". You're not specifying an aggregate.

Comment: In addition, you can simplify this to `dt.Compute("SUM(1)", "'Test'='Test'")`, you don't need a case statement at all.

Comment: @GarethD  I need a case statement cause i need something like this
`Case When 'Test'='Test' Then 2+3 Else 5+5 End`

Comment: For whoever demoted all the answers, share your dislikes so we could all learn...unless you are just playing here!

Answer (score 0):

[`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method takes *expression* as a first parameter and takes *filter* as a second.

> The expression parameter requires an aggregate function.

Looks like you must use one of aggregate functions on it.

- [`Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Also take a look [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Comment: I do not think this is the right answer - `dt.Compute( "1=1", "")` works perfectly fine. And there are no aggregate functions here. Even `dt.Compute( "'Test'='Test'", "")` works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linq query with lambda expression. For example (Assuming you need Sum);

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Sum(d=>d.Field<string>("Test") == "Test"? 1:0);
```

Comment: Wow, this looks way more elegant then my solution.

Comment: Yes @Serv, it is easy with LINQ.

Comment: I used Linq to, but I was a bit cautious, because of the Sum function firing upon a string column and replacing it with integer values.

Comment: @Serv, Sum function is not firing on string here. Based on the string value it is either adding a 1 or 0 both are integers.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Compute("IIF('Test'='Test',1,0)", "")`

Try this instead.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.80).aspx

The syntax is:

```
dt.Compute(expression, filter);
```

The `expression` needs to be an aggregating function like Sum, Count or Average.

The `filter` part sets the fields, which are used with the expression. If your column is called `colTest` and the field should contain `Test` your filter would be: `colTest == 'Test'`

**EDIT**

From what I understand you have a column where you want to change the content if a certain field contains "Test".

I have written this quick mockup to demonstrate how it can be accomplished without `dt.Compute()`

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ValueToChange", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add(1, "1");
table.Rows.Add(2, "0");
table.Rows.Add(3, "1");
table.Rows.Add(4, "0");
table.Rows.Add(5, "1");

//Select all Rows in which the column Test is "1"
var rows = table.AsEnumerable().Where (t => t.Field<string>("Test") == "1");
foreach (var x in rows)
{
    //set the field ValueToChange to "changed"
    x.SetField("ValueToChange", "changed");
    //linqpad output. ignore it
    x.Dump();
}
```

This may not be excatly your scenario, but you can adapt it in a few quick steps.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something similar to this:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows
{
    if (some condition)
       dt.Rows[r]["yourTargetColumnName"]=true;
    else
       dt.Rows[r]["yourTargetColumnName"]=false;
}
```

The above code will set your target column with either true or false based on the test condition you have. If the objective is to address a specific row, remove the foreach and adjust the indices appropriately.